# Microsoft SQL Server Version Upgrade without Downtime

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to upgrade a Microsoft SQL Server to a new Version without any Downtime? I read about Availability Groups, but have no practical Experience and i am confused now. Please help me to understand. And must i buy the Enterprise Edition?

Comment: Have you read? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/upgrading-always-on-availability-group-replica-instances?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You don't have to buy the Enterprise Edition, but the Standard Edition is able to use only Basic Availability Groups which have some limitations. The most important one, in my opinion, support for one availability database, so if you have several databases, you will have to create a Basic Availability Group for each one. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/basic-availability-groups-always-on-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Now I read this article, but i am still confused. I do not understand if Availibilty Groups eliminates the Downtime during Version Upgrade.

Comment: The downtime will be equal to the failover time (it depends on your system workload and could be from zero to several seconds).

Comment: What about running Applications during the Failovertime; are they abending?

Comment: >>>don't have to buy the Enterprise Edition<<< of SQL Server. But what about Windows Server? To support WSFC you need to buy Enterprise Edition or Datacenter Edition

Comment: Create a new server with the latest version you want. Restore the data from live database to the newly created database. Enable log shipping. Switch the database by changing the public IP. We hardly have 2 minutes downtime. I know this may not be appropriate answer.. but just gave my thoughts

Comment: Mr Gaonkar, so you have a little Downtime. And running Applications will abend.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to buy Enterprise Edition to upgrade the SQL server but keep your databackup handy when upgrading the SQL server.

To upgrade to a different edition of SQL Server
Insert the SQL Server installation media. From the root folder, double-click setup.exe or launch the SQL Server Installation Center from Configuration Tools. To install from a network share, locate the root folder on the share, and then double-click Setup.exe.

To upgrade an existing instance of SQL Server to a different edition, from the SQL Server Installation Center click Maintenance, and then select Edition Upgrade.

If Setup support files are required, SQL Server Setup installs them. If you are instructed to restart your computer, restart before you continue.

The System Configuration Checker runs a discovery operation on your computer. To continue, click OK.

On the Product Key page, select a radio button to indicate whether you are upgrading to a free edition of SQL Server, or whether you have a PID key for a production version of the product. For more information, see Editions and Components of SQL Server and Supported Version and Edition Upgrades.

On the License Terms page, read the license agreement, and then select the check box to accept the licensing terms and conditions. To continue, click Next. To end Setup, click Cancel.

On the Select Instance page, specify the instance of SQL Server to upgrade.

The Edition Upgrade Rules page validates your computer configuration before the edition upgrade operation begins.

The Ready to Upgrade Edition page shows a tree view of installation options that were specified during Setup. To continue, click Upgrade.

During the edition upgrade process, the services need to be restarted to pick up the new setting. After edition upgrade, the Complete page provides a link to the summary log file for the edition upgrade. To close the wizard, click Close.

The Complete page provides a link to the summary log file for the installation and other important notes.

If you are instructed to restart the computer, do so now. It is important to read the message from the Installation Wizard when you are done with Setup. For information about Setup log files, see View and Read SQL Server Setup Log Files.

If you upgraded from SQL Server Express, you must perform additional steps before you can use your upgraded instance of SQL Server:

Enable the SQL Server Agent service in Windows SCM.

Provision the SQL Server Agent service account by using SQL Server Configuration Manager.

In addition to the steps above, you may need to do the following if you upgraded from SQL Server Express:

Users that were provisioned in SQL Server Express remain provisioned after the upgrade. Specifically, the BUILTIN\Users group remains provisioned. Disable, remove, or reprovision these accounts as needed. For more information, see Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions.

Sizes and recovery mode for the tempdb and model system databases remain unchanged after the upgrade. Reconfigure these settings as needed. For more information, see Back Up and Restore of System Databases (SQL Server).

Template databases remain on the computer after the upgrade.

Reference: Solution from [Microsoft Official website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-to-a-different-edition-of-sql-server-setup?view=sql-server-ver16)